# bin/rails aborted! Load Error: 126: The specified module could not be found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7

i am trying to create an application named blog using rails and i encountered the following error message, What can i do to resolve this?

```
bin/rails aborted!
LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/puma_http11.so (LoadError)
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
C:/Users/ahmed/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
C:/Users/ahmed/blog/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Users/ahmed/blog/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
bin/rails aborted!
LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/lib/puma/puma_http11.so (LoadError)
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
C:/Users/ahmed/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
C:/Users/ahmed/blog/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Users/ahmed/blog/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have done gem cleanups, uninstalled and reinstalled bundler, rails, puma but still the issue persists.

Comment: I would start with `bundle install`, if it still happens check if the gem is even there `ls C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.4.2/`. I never used Ruby on Windows, but issues like that typically happen after updates when some dependency goes missing.

Comment: What is the output from `ruby -rpuma -e "puts Puma::MiniSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION"`?